# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, erb

O interpretador do Rails está me mandando essa mensagem na seguinte linha de código:

```
...
<li>
  <%= form_tag("search", { method: "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" }) do %>
    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      <%= text_field_tag (:q, nil , { class: "form-control", height: "25", width: "25" } ) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<li>
...
```

Deve ter algo errado na passagem do hash do form_tag ou do text_field_tag mas não consigo identificar

Comment: como o erro diz, ele esta esperando fechar a função com ) e você esta incluindo mais um parâmetro não esperado... verifique qual é a linha exata do erro e reveja se todos os parâmetros são esperados.

Comment: A mensagem de erro sem dúvida inclui o número exato da linha e a posição do caractere dessa linha. Verifique isso.

Comment: Consegui aqui, a linha do erro era essa:
`<%= text_field_tag (:q, nil , { class: "form-control", height: "25", width: "25" } ) %>`

Troquei por:
`<%= text_field_tag :q, nil, { class: "form-control", size: "25x25" } %>`
E funcionou ... Só não sei o por que...

Comment: @Awkward Publique a solução como resposta e marque-a como aceita

Comment: @Andrey Não publiquei como resposta, pois, mesmo solucionando o problema eu não sabia o por que. O Guilherme fez um ótimo trabalho explicando. Da próxima vez eu coloco como resposta, faz mais sentido mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema:

```
text_field_tag (:q, nil , { class: "form-control", height: "25", width: "25" } )
```

Pondo de forma simples, você tem o seguinte:

```
funcao (1, 2, 3)
```

Repare no espaço antes da abertura dos parênteses. Isso é fundamental. O ruby permite que passe argumentos para uma função se nenhum parênteses for usado, e ao mesmo tempo permite o uso de parênteses para agrupar expressões simples, como `(1+5)*2`. O que acontece ali é que por conta desse espaço ele tentar ler como se tivesse passando um único argumento: a expressão dentro dos parênteses. E ai está o problema, não é para ter uma vírgula no meio da expressão. Correção:

```
funcao(1, 2, 3)
```

Ou se preferir:

```
funcao 1, 2, 3
```

---

Nota, no caso particular de passar um Hash como último argumento da função, você pode omitir as chaves para melhorar legibilidade. Se quiser, ainda pode escrever assim:

```
text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "form-control", height: "25", width: "25")
```